# Вывод заранее известного значения в textbox, при выборе определенного значения в combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Есть форма для создания нового самолета, большинство данных пользователь вводит сам, но значения полей: масса, размах крыла, длина и высота заранее определены для каждого самолета.
Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе какого-то самолета из combobox-а, в textbox-ы: масса, размах крыла, длина, высота выводились готовые значения?
Главный вопрос, куда это вставить в коде?

[image: Форма]

Comment: Посмотри в сторону событий. Selected*Changed, например. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте класс-модель самолёта:

```
public class Plane
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    // и другие необходимые свойства
}
```

Объявите коллекцию самолётов:

```
List<Plane> planes;
```

Тем или иным образом заполните эту коллекцию:

```
planes = new List<Plane>
{
    new Plane { Type="A", Weight=1000 },
    new Plane { Type="B", Weight=1500 },
    new Plane { Type="C", Weight=2000 }
};
```

Эти данные, например, могут загружаться из файла.

Теперь сделаем привязку этой коллекции к нужным контролам:

```
comboBoxType.DisplayMember = "Type";
comboBoxType.DataSource = planes;

textBoxWeight.DataBindings.Add("Text", planes, "Weight");
```

Привязку нужно делать после загрузки данных.

Готово!

Теперь, при выборе в комбобоксе типа самолёта будет автоматически изменяться значение массы в текстбоксе.