# Как связать ComboBox и TextBox?

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе категории в ComboBox менялся текст в TextBox? В visual Studio.

Comment: Тип приложения надо угадать?

Comment: возможные дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/680465/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1195928/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/668738/178576) и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

При подаче вопросы не забывайте давать максимум информации о том, что вам нужно. Иначе вам просто никто не ответит.

Зависит от того, какой фреймворк или графическую подсистему вы используете. Для Asp.NET ответ будет один, для WPF другой, для Windows Forms - третий...

Но если ответить более или менее абстрактно: ищите среди методов своего комбобокса что-нибудь с названием "ValueChanged" или "SelectedItemChanged" и в теле этого метода прописывайте необходимые реакции других компонентов:

К примеру, для WinForms в самом примитивном варианте это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ComboBox.Enabled)
{
     TextBox.Text = "Тут могла быть ваша реклама";         
}
```

вот так вот?